# Import and run a maven project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to import an existing maven project in Eclipse, but I am not sure how I get everything to run properly. 
The project structure is as follows:
One main directoy with a `pom.xml` and 5 subfolders/subprojects each with a `pom.xml`.
I searched some posts regarding this and came up with the following procedure:

1. I installed the m2e plugin in Eclipse via Help > Install new
   Software.
   Eclipse version: 2019-06 (4.12.0), m2e version: 1.12.0.20190529-1916
2. Import > Existing Maven Projects > Choose main directory as the root. It then shows me the main folder and the 5 sub folders and then click finish.

In my project explorer I now have a working set that includes all subprojects as simple folders. Also, all subfolders are now listed individually, is that supposed to be? On top of that, in these subprojects the paths are duplicate (see screenshot), i.e. I have a src>main>java all-in-one directory and then a regular src>main>java path. Why is that?

[image: i]

3. I right click on the workspace (not individual subproject) > Run as > Maven build
4. Set goal to "eclipse:eclipse" and run. It then tells me that the build was successful.

Now I am wondering if these steps were correct and how I can run the code of a specific subproject? Do I also have to build these individually or was it enough to build just the workspace?.

pom.xml of the main directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.uniriotec</groupId>
  <artifactId>NlgFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>Machine-Artifact</module>
    <module>General-Language-Common</module>
    <module>Portuguese-Realizer</module>
    <module>English-Realizer</module>
    <module>BPM2NLG</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

right click your project and look for maven -> update project
this should work.

Though your structure looks strange. You can checkout the subProjects on their own as own projects and compile them with maven one after another

Comment: So you mean importing them all one by one as separate projects? Instead of importing the main directory

Comment: depending on the configuration, this could solve it. You need to provide the source code or at least your poms to clear this. Did you try maven -> update?

Comment: Updating made no difference, but I keep it the way it is now. The respective .java files I want to run work nonetheless now.

Comment: ok, you could try to call "mvn clean" and "mvn install" from your subprojects, or try to build all the subprojects first and then the parent project

Answer (score 0):

```
By looking at the screen shot i think there is only one project, having multiple source file organised in multiple packages. 
Please share your project over git or may be your pom file so that we can help you here.
Note - I think you were using maven eclipse:eclipse plugin which is used to generate eclipse .project and .classfile which is a metdata file about project and used by eclipse.
```